# How do i get my textures back after retopology?

Tags: texturing, uv, retopology

[image]

After retopology i get this , i try to transfer data and stuff , but nothing happens , how to i get my texture back?

FILE: https://filebin.net/k1hx9vtyhpfyz0vf

Comment: "i try to transfer data and stuff" There exists a wealth of interesting but unexplicated details in that tiny aside.

Answer (score 3):

You need to bake your textures from your high poly mesh onto your low poly mesh. There are plenty tutorials for that on YouTube. You should search for e.g. "Bake High Poly To Low Poly".